# How to convert an MD5 hash to a string and use it as a file name

Tags: c#, md5

I am taking the MD5 hash of an image file and I want to use the hash as a filename.

How do I convert the hash to a string that is valid filename?

EDIT: `toString()` just gives "System.Byte[]"

Comment: You want to get the hash as hex not binary... I don't do c# though so I don't know how

Comment: Just as a heads up, you might want to use SHAx since MD5 is being phased out.

Comment: The only reason to discontinue using MD5 is because of the cryptographic attacks against it recently (same with SHA-0/1).  If you're not using it for cryptographic reasons, there's no big hurry to change over.

Comment: For simple hashing without security considerations MD5 should still be enough.

Answer (score 21):

How about this:

```
string filename = BitConverter.ToString(yourMD5ByteArray);
```

If you prefer a shorter filename without hyphens then you can just use:

```
string filename =
    BitConverter.ToString(yourMD5ByteArray).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Note this uses hexadecimal encoding.

Answer (score 11):

[System.Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(loband).aspx)

As a commenter pointed out -- normal base 64 encoding can contain a '/' character, which obivously will be a problem with filenames.  However, there are other characters that are usable, such as an underscore - just replace all the '/' with an underscore.

```
string filename = Convert.ToBase64String(md5HashBytes).Replace("/","_");
```

Comment: I am gettig an error using that and if try with say test.jpg it works??

Comment: Looking at it there is "/" in the string and error is cannot find part pf path??

Comment: Either remove all "/" characters or use the approach I suggest in my answer.

Comment: You will need to convert all the / and + characters to, say, _ and - characters instead.

Comment: "+" characters are not prohibited, no need to remove them.

Comment: Converting to base 64 could have been a good idea, if it where not for the strange characters  such as + - /  that happens a lot when you use this encoding and that filesystems and parsers don't like

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(md5HashBytes);
string hashString = guid.ToString("N"); 
// format: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

string hashString = guid.ToString("D"); 
// format: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

string hashString = guid.ToString("B"); 
// format: {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

string hashString = guid.ToString("P"); 
// format: (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

Comment: Guid.ToString() uses NOT the sequential order of the originating byte array!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the safest for file names. You always get a hex string and never worry about / or +, etc.

```
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        string hashed = sBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sample")));
//input "sample" returns = Xo/5v1W6NQgZnSLphBKb5g==
```

or

```
string Hash = BitConverter.ToString(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sample")));
//input "sample" returns = 5E-8F-F9-BF-55-BA-35-08-19-9D-22-E9-84-12-9B-E6
```

Comment: Note that Base64 produces case-sensitive names because it uses both capital and lower letters. Windows file systems are case-insensitive so be carefull with that.

Answer (score 1):

Technically using Base64 is bad if this is Windows, filenames are case insensitive (at least in explorers view).. but in base64, 'a' is different to 'A', this means that perhaps unlikely but you end up with even higher rate of collision..

A better alternative is hexadecimal like the bitconverter class, or if you can- use base32 encoding (which after removing the padding from both base64 and base32, and in the case of 128bit, will give you similar length filenames).

Answer (score 1):

Try Base32 hash of MD5. It gives filename-safe case insensitive strings.

```
    string Base32Hash(string input)
    {
        byte[] buf = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        return String.Join("", buf.Select(b => "abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz234567"[b & 0x1F]));
    }
```

Comment: Please note that MD5 is not FIPS-compliant and will throw exception on machines with FIPS-enabled. Use SHA1 instead.